# I want to download and upload a pdf after creating it from html using javascript

Tags: pdfmake

HERE is the code i used to download the file.

I want to upload the same file to server.

The file was created from html.

```
$scope.callPdf = function (studentId) {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('download'), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var data = canvas.toDataURL();
            var docDefinition = { content: [{ image: data, width: 450 }] };
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download(studentId + ".pdf");
        }
    });

}`
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use getDataURL method and receive store it in variable and then use it for upload.

```
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).getDataUrl(function(dataUrl){
var pdfFile = dataUrl;
//upload code goes here
});
```